# Rename and save ActiveDocument with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is it possible to rename the activedocument (the word document that I'm running the macro from) with VBA?

Right now I'm saving my activedocument under a new name and then attempt to delete the original. The latter part won't go through, so the original never gets deleted.

Anyone know if this is even possible?

Comment: Since the active document is open, you cannot delete it... You'd have to close it and delete it from the freshly saved file. (Although I have doubts it'll work, considering permissions and such...)

Comment: If you do Save As doesn't that new file become the current document? If it does then there shouldn't be problem deleting the old file, no?

Comment: True, but since the old file is closed, the Sub that was running also stops. (Therefore, no other code is executed.)

Comment: Would it be possible to call a function from the Normal template before control is lost that subsequently deletes the old file?

Pretty far fetched but I'm just wondering...

Comment: Like I said, as long as the active document is open, you cannot delete it. It would have to be closed before it can be deleted... There is, however a `Workbook_Open()` event. If there's any way you can use that...

Comment: It sounds like you need an addin, i.e., a "neutral spot" from which you can create and delete these versions.

Answer (score 1):

I spent a lot of time doing this recently, because I disliked having to delete previous files when I did "Save As" - I wanted a "Save as and delete old file" answer. My answer is copied from [here](https://superuser.com/q/591143/143629).

I added it to the quicklaunch bar which works wonderfully.

1. Insert following code into normal.dotm template (found in `C:\Documents and Settings\user name\Application Data\Microsoft\Templates` for Windows 7 for Word)
2. Save normal.dotm
3. Add this to the quicklaunch toolbar in Word.
4. Optional - remap a keyboard shortcut to this
5. Optional - digitally sign your template (recommended)

Note this actually moves the old file to the Recycle Bin rather than trashing completely and also sets the new file name in a very convenient fashion.

---

```
Option Explicit

 'To send a file to the recycle bin, we'll need to use the Win32 API
 'We'll be using the SHFileOperation function which uses a 'struct'
 'as an argument. That struct is defined here:
Private Type SHFILEOPSTRUCT
    hwnd As Long
    wFunc As Long
    pFrom As String
    pTo As String
    fFlags As Integer
    fAnyOperationsAborted As Long
    hNameMappings As Long
    lpszProgressTitle As Long
End Type

 ' function declaration:
Private Declare Function SHFileOperation Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "SHFileOperationA" (lpFileOp As SHFILEOPSTRUCT) As Long

 'there are some constants to declare too
Private Const FO_DELETE = &H3
Private Const FOF_ALLOWUNDO = &H40
Private Const FOF_NOCONFIRMATION = &H10
Private Const FOF_SILENT = &H4

Function RecycleFile(FileName As String, Optional UserConfirm As Boolean = True, Optional HideErrors As Boolean = False) As Long
     'This function takes one mandatory argument (the file to be recycled) and two
     'optional arguments: UserConfirm is used to determine if the "Are you sure..." dialog
     'should be displayed before deleting the file and HideErrors is used to determine
     'if any errors should be shown to the user

    Dim ptFileOp As SHFILEOPSTRUCT
     'We have declared FileOp as a SHFILEOPSTRUCT above, now to fill it:
    With ptFileOp
        .wFunc = FO_DELETE
        .pFrom = FileName
        .fFlags = FOF_ALLOWUNDO
        If Not UserConfirm Then .fFlags = .fFlags + FOF_NOCONFIRMATION
        If HideErrors Then .fFlags = .fFlags + FOF_SILENT
    End With
     'Note that the entire struct wasn't populated, so it would be legitimate to change it's
     'declaration above and remove the unused elements. The reason we don't do that is that the
     'struct is used in many operations, some of which may utilise those elements

     'Now invoke the function and return the long from the call as the result of this function
    RecycleFile = SHFileOperation(ptFileOp)

End Function


Sub renameAndDelete()

    ' Store original name
    Dim sOriginalName As String
    sOriginalName = ActiveDocument.FullName

    ' Save As
    Dim sFilename As String, fDialog As FileDialog, ret As Long
    Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

    'set initial name so you don't have to navigate to
    fDialog.InitialFileName = sOriginalName

    ret = fDialog.Show

    If ret <> 0 Then
        sFilename = fDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set fDialog = Nothing

    'only do this if the file names are different...
    If (sFilename <> sOriginalName) Then
        'I love vba's pretty code
         ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=sFilename, FileFormat:= _
            wdFormatXMLDocument, LockComments:=False, Password:="", AddToRecentFiles _
            :=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, EmbedTrueTypeFonts _
            :=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData:=False, _
            SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, CompatibilityMode:=14

        ' Delete original (don't care about errors, I guess)
        Dim hatersGonnaHate As Integer
        hatersGonnaHate = RecycleFile(sOriginalName, False, True)

    End If

End Sub
```